# In LESS how would I have a mix-in return values to a collection of classes

Tags: css, less

For instance, lets say I have the following:

```
.document {
    header {
        color: blue;
    }
    footer {
        color: red
    }
}
```

Desired results:

```
.my_document {
    .document;
 }
```

such that .document; is replaced with

```
header {
    color: blue;
}
footer {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://lesscss.org:

> You can also use **[parametric mixins](http://lesscss.org#-parametric-mixins)** which don’t take parameters. This
>   is useful if you want to hide the ruleset from the CSS output, but
>   want to include its properties in other rulesets:

```
.wrap () {   
   text-wrap: wrap;   
   white-space: pre-wrap;  
   white-space:
   -moz-pre-wrap;   word-wrap: break-word; 
}

pre { .wrap }
```

So in your case use:

```
.document() {
    header {
        color: blue;
    }
    footer {
        color: red
    }
}
.my_document {
    .document;
 }
```

(try running the above code in http://less2css.org)

---

I'm not too sure, but I think that in older versions of LESS you had to call these mixins with parentheses like so

```
.my_document {
  .document(); 
}
```